Is it possible to automatically set the label-width in tasks to be the minimum possible to accommodate all labels?
Is it possible to automatically set the label-width in tasks to be the minimum possible to accommodate all labels?
Currently, label-width is defaulted to 1em and when the label's width exceeds that, it issues a warning telling me a minimum value that the label-width must be. I usually set it a pt above that.
This is tedious to do for a lot of environments. Is there an automatic way?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label-width=auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[label=(\alph*)]
    \task Hello,
    \task Sir!
\end{tasks}
\end{document}


enumerate is capable of this, so I think it should be possible in tasks

Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731185/ would be an option?

Or if you know what the longest label will probably be but (like (w) for example) but you don't know how wide that is (like 1.5em) then you could use \widthof and add 1pt automatically with the calc package.

@Marijn I wasn't aware of that package, but it does look like it fits my needs. Choosing the longest letter and using calc is a bit tedious for all of the environments I'm working with (which use different counters). Thank you for your suggestions
